# letsencrypt setup to GCP CDN

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, cdn

I've setup my Google Cloud Project to use a load balancer in combination with auto scaling instance templates. Currently the instance group only has one instance.
 
My domain name successfully refers to the load balancers IP. Till these steps everything is working correctly.
 
Now I want to setup SSL for this project. I would like to do this with the Letsencrypt service, however I'm having no success when trying to set this up.
 
In the Google Cloud Engine load balancer window there is an option to setup an earlier created certificate with Google Cloud shell to the load balancer frontend. Unfortunately I can only create a .csr and .key file with the Google Cloud Shell. Furthermore, I can create an unsafe ssl certificate and get the .cert file from it, but I would like to create a safe SSL cert file using letsencrypt. The Letsencrypt services requires direct access to the domain from to command line interface the commando was executed on, this is probably the reason why I’m getting an error indicating the domain name cannot be retrieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one https://hub.docker.com/r/bloomapi/letsencrypt-gcloud-balancer
P.S the certificates on the load balancer will automatically renew every month